# Knowledge Articles Scheduled Publication - What is the exact time?

Tags: knowledge, articles, schedule

I am interested to know the exact time of the article publication, after we schedule it from the Article Management Tab. I haven't been able to find any documentation of this detail. To help you recognise the process which I am refering to, pleas refer to this screenshot:

[image]

Anyone has any idea what is the specific time of this publications?

Thanks in advance.
E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The articles are published at 12 AM in the midnight of the set date.
Suppose you have scheduled the article for publishing on 1st January, then it will be published 12 AM of 1st January.

This screenshot might help you.
[image]

Thanks,
Girish